# create a stacked bar chart in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, stackedbarseries

Hi I am trying to create a stacked bar chart in matlab but the output graph seems to be adding the first data set (AD_monthly_generation_250) to the second one (CC_monthly_demand_2012). How can I avoid this?

my code is

```
%% AD STACKED CC %%

AD_monthly_generation_250 = [186 186 186 186 186 186 186 186 186 186 186 186]';
CC_monthly_demand_2012 = [199.575 206.701 145.284 135.944 127.689 93.281 80.311 78.859 98.145 168.572 206.365 113.030]';


% Create a stacked bar chart using the bar function
figure;
bar(1:12, [ AD_monthly_generation_250 CC_monthly_demand_2012 ], 0.5, 'stack');


% Add title and axis labels
title('Seasonal Anaerobic Digestion (250kWe) Supply to Demand - 2012','FontSize',22);
 set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',' Sep',     'Oct', 'Nov',' Dec'},'FontSize',18)
 ylabel('Energy (MWh)');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `'stack'` option works as is supposed to... Try this code, maybe it's what you wanted:

```
%% AD STACKED CC %%

AD_monthly_generation_250 = [186 186 186 186 186 186 186 186 186 186 186 186]';
CC_monthly_demand_2012 = [199.575 206.701 145.284 135.944 127.689 93.281 80.311 78.859 98.145 168.572 206.365 113.030]';

% Create a stacked bar chart using the bar function
figure;
% bar(1:12, [ AD_monthly_generation_250 CC_monthly_demand_2012 ], 0.5, 'stack');
bar(1:12, AD_monthly_generation_250, 0.5, 'b');
hold on;
bar(1:12, CC_monthly_demand_2012, 0.5, 'r');
hold off;

% Add title and axis labels
title('Seasonal Anaerobic Digestion (250kWe) Supply to Demand - 2012','FontSize',22);
 set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',' Sep',     'Oct', 'Nov',' Dec'},'FontSize',18)
 ylabel('Energy (MWh)');
```

Comment: thanks but that doesn't seem to work. All I get is a bar chart with the same y axis value of AD_monthly_generation_250

Comment: @user643469: I commented by mistake one of the lines. I updated the code in the above answer. Could you try again, please?